# pandas.read_csv() returns strings from columns instead numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to find linear regression plot for the data provided

```
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot

data = pandas.read_csv('cost_revenue_clean.csv')
data.describe()

X = DataFrame(data,columns=['production_budget_usd'])
y = DataFrame(data,columns=['worldwide_gross_usd'])
```

when I try to plot it

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(X,y)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

the plot was completely empty
and when I printed the type of X

```
for element in X:
    print(type(element))
```

it shows the type is string.. Where am I standing wrong???

Comment: The code you used for printing the types does not do what you think it does. `for element in X` loops on column names, that's why the type is `str`. And as hinted by @tdy, your lines for building `X` and `y` don't select single columns in your source dataframe, that probably doesn't help getting a proper plot.

Comment: when i simply Printed  X, it shows instead of numbers i was getting NaN for every entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to make new DataFrames for `X` and `y`. Try [**`astype(float)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) if you want them as numeric:

```py
X = data['production_budget_usd'].astype(float)
y = data['worldwide_gross_usd'].astype(float)
```

Comment: this was not helpful it generated a KeyError

Comment: @gyanmishra If it generates a `KeyError`, then your dataframe does not actually have columns like `production_budget_usd` and `worldwide_gross_usd` as your code suggests. I suggest editing your post and copy-pasting `data.head()`.

Comment: yeah you are right there was an extra space in the field declaration at the end which was normally not visible. Thank you for the support.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted out.